# T-SQL assign NULL to Text type field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to execute next code to replace all empty strings to NULL, where column type is TEXT. But this code seems to do nothing.

```
UPDATE mytable SET textField = NULL WHERE DATALENGTH(textField)=0
```

What is right way here to null this column?

UPD. OK, this is really work. It was just weird data showing of Embarcadero DBArtasian

Comment: That should work. Presumably you don't have any truly empty strings.

Comment: Is your table name `table`? You should put square brackets around it like so: `[table]`

Comment: @Jeff it just for example, not real name of table

Comment: @Martin Smith - I checked with SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATALENGTH(textField)=0  and there are a lot of empty text fields

Comment: Well there's no reason why those wouldn't qualify for the `UPDATE` too then. Any triggers on the table?

Comment: Also, does your update query actually return "0 rows affected", or did you determine that it does nothing some other way?

Comment: @Martin Smith so, its works, see update on question

Answer (score 2):

Your way is correct.
Play a little with CAST and RTRIM, maybe you have some spaces in the field.

Answer (score 2):

Please convert the Text field to varchar, since LEN cannot be used on Text fields. This worked for me

UPDATE mytable 
SET textField = NULL 
WHERE LEN(convert(varchar(1000),textField )) = 0

Answer (score 0):

probabily the where condition does not return anything

try do do the below to see how many record will be affected

```
SELECT * from Table WHERE DATALENGTH(textField)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET textField = NULL 
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(textField))) = 0
```

Comment: You can't use any of those functions on a `text` column. And wouldn't need to trim anyway as `LEN` ignores trailing space.